# Восстановить репликацию PostgrySQL

Tags: postgresql, дублирование

Как перезапустить репликацию? Имеются два сервера, на одном из них перезапустил службу postgrysql предположительно на мастере.

Результат в логе.
2021-01-20 13:16:49.578 +06 [12298] LOG:  replication terminated by primary server
2021-01-20 13:16:49.578 +06 [12298] DETAIL:  End of WAL reached on timeline 1 at 1374/88D18BF8.
2021-01-20 13:16:49.578 +06 [12298] FATAL:  could not send end-of-streaming message to primary: no COPY in progress
2021-01-20 13:16:49.578 +06 [2341] LOG:  record with incorrect prev-link 0/4054A806 at 1374/88D18BF8
2021-01-20 13:16:52.604 +06 [22399] FATAL:  could not connect to the primary server: server closed the connection unexpectedly
This probably means the server terminated abnormally
before or while processing the request.
2021-01-20 13:16:54.298 +06 [22411] postgres@aparudb ERROR:  current database is not configured as pglogical node
2021-01-20 13:16:54.298 +06 [22411] postgres@aparudb HINT:  create pglogical node first
2021-01-20 13:16:54.298 +06 [22411] postgres@aparudb STATEMENT:  SELECT status from pglogical.show_subscription_status() where subscription_name = 'subscriber1';
2021-01-20 13:16:54.589 +06 [22412] LOG:  started streaming WAL from primary at 1374/88000000 on timeline 1
2021-01-20 13:16:54.865 +06 [2341] FATAL:  hot standby is not possible because max_connections = 350 is a lower setting than on the master server (its value was 450)
2021-01-20 13:16:54.865 +06 [2341] CONTEXT:  WAL redo at 1374/88D18BF8 for XLOG/PARAMETER_CHANGE: max_connections=450 max_worker_processes=32 max_prepared_xacts=0 max_locks_per_xact=64 wal_level=logical wal
_log_hints=off track_commit_timestamp=off
2021-01-20 13:16:55.547 +06 [2340] LOG:  startup process (PID 2341) exited with exit code 1
2021-01-20 13:16:55.547 +06 [2340] LOG:  terminating any other active server processes
2021-01-20 13:16:55.547 +06 [15645] postgres@postgres WARNING:  terminating connection because of crash of another server process
2021-01-20 13:16:55.547 +06 [15645] postgres@postgres DETAIL:  The postmaster has commanded this server process to roll back the current transaction and exit, because another server process exited abnormall
y and possibly corrupted shared memory.
2021-01-20 13:16:55.547 +06 [15645] postgres@postgres HINT:  In a moment you should be able to reconnect to the database and repeat your command.
2021-01-20 13:16:55.547 +06 [5988] postgres@postgres WARNING:  terminating connection because of crash of another server process
2021-01-20 13:16:55.547 +06 [5988] postgres@postgres DETAIL:  The postmaster has commanded this server process to roll back the current transaction and exit, because another server process exited abnormally
and possibly corrupted shared memory.
2021-01-20 13:16:55.547 +06 [5988] postgres@postgres HINT:  In a moment you should be able to reconnect to the database and repeat your command.
2021-01-20 13:16:57.508 +06 [2340] LOG:  database system is shut down

2021-01-20 17:31:44.129 +06 [1686] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
2021-01-20 17:31:44.130 +06 [1686] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
2021-01-20 17:31:44.148 +06 [1686] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2021-01-20 17:31:44.563 +06 [1687] LOG:  database system was interrupted while in recovery at log time 2021-01-20 13:09:27 +06
2021-01-20 17:31:44.563 +06 [1687] HINT:  If this has occurred more than once some data might be corrupted and you might need to choose an earlier recovery target.
2021-01-20 17:31:49.453 +06 [1687] LOG:  entering standby mode
2021-01-20 17:31:49.478 +06 [1687] FATAL:  hot standby is not possible because max_connections = 350 is a lower setting than on the master server (its value was 450)
2021-01-20 17:31:49.482 +06 [1686] LOG:  startup process (PID 1687) exited with exit code 1
2021-01-20 17:31:49.483 +06 [1686] LOG:  aborting startup due to startup process failure
2021-01-20 17:31:49.526 +06 [1686] LOG:  database system is shut down
pg_ctl: could not start server
Examine the log output.

Answer (score 1):

> hot standby is not possible because max_connections = 350 is a lower
> setting than on the master server (its value was 450)

[Есть несколько настроек](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/REL_13_STABLE/src/backend/access/transam/xlog.c#L6276), значения которых не могут быть на реплике меньше, чем на мастере. `max_connections` среди них.

В тексте ошибки прямым текстом сказано и какая настройка является проблемой и не меньше какого значения она должна быть. Вам необходимо исправить конфигурацию СУБД.

Comment: Есть ли надежда Что поправив конфиг репликация возобновится? Поправив лог надо ли будет перезапускать postgresql? Останавливать сервер нельзя! И так был сбой при перезагрузке, минут 10 сервисы не работали, приблизительно 100 запросов в секунду. Если можно пошагово что нужно сделать

Comment: `Останавливать сервер нельзя!` - в смысле? Он и так не запущен и намеренно отказывается стартовать по этой самой причине.

Comment: Почему различия в конфигурационных фаилах не мешали нормальной работе  до перезагрузки сервиса Postgresql?

Comment: А почему должны были мешать? max_connections только при старте базы и может быть задан. Он не поменяется в запущенном экземпляре даже если reload запросите.